# DBA_HIST_SNAPSHOT vs. DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY retention period

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, awr

On an 11.2.0.3.0 instance the AWR retention period is 8 days.  Data in `DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY` starts from 2014-04-30 but the corresponding `SNAP_ID` is not available in `DBA_HIST_SNAPSHOT`.  `DBA_HIST_SNAPSHOT` only has data starting from 2004-05-11.

Why do these tables have different retention preiods?